# how to secure pdf with password in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, security, pdf

> how to secure pdf with password in laravel ?

```
$users = DB::table('products')->get();
$pdf = PDF::loadView('data',compact('users'));
$pdf->SetProtection(['copy', 'print'], '', 'pass');

return $pdf->download('data.pdf');
```

Comment: What pdf library/package are you using?

Comment: Your code looks like the examples at https://github.com/niklasravnsborg/laravel-pdf - what does not work with it?

Answer (score 0):

According to https://mpdf.github.io/reference/mpdf-functions/setprotection.html, the `SetProtection` method takes up to four parameters: a list of permissions, a user password, an owner password, and the bit-length for the encryption.

If you leave the second parameter, the user password, empty, no password is required for reading the document. So, most probably, you want to use a more complex password than the empty string for your document ;)